# How to round decimal values on aggregate function?

Tags: r

I'm coding product unit cost.

Is there any short version of round values while I aggregate my data?

```
#Product unit cost
Summary.Cost <- aggregate(Toplam.TL, list(Product.Name = BOM$Product.Name), sum)
Total.Cost <- round(Summary.Cost[2],2)
Summary.Cost <- cbind(Summary.Cost[1],Total.Cost)
colnames(Summary.Cost) <- c("Product Name", "Total (TL)")

Summary.Cost
write.xlsx(Summary.Cost, "attempt.xlsx", "Sheet 1",row.names = F)
```

**Output**

```
       Product Name   Total(TL)
    1             A        3.91
    2             B        4.00
    3             C        3.92
    4             D        4.28
    5             E       82.65
    6             F        3.95
    7             G       21.35
    8             H       14.64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please share your data using `dput()`. Example combining round and sum in aggregation below

```
Summary.Cost <- aggregate(Toplam.TL, list(Product.Name = BOM$Product.Name), FUN = function(x) round(sum(x), 2))
```